# What would have been the other stops of Amelia Earhart's ill fated last voyage?

Tags: aviation-history

Having just watched *Amelia - A tale of two sisters*, I wondered whether, had she landed successfully on Howland Island, what, or where, would the remaining *subsequent* stops for the rest of her equatorial journey, in 1937, been?

Were there any other stages that would have been as equally, or more, dangerous, and liable to failure, or was the stage at which she tragically failed the most dangerous of all of the journey's stops?

[This image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Earhart_locations.png) from the Wikipedia page, [Amelia Earhart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelia_Earhart), implies that she would have flown on to Honolulu, but the text doesn't state that fact explicitly:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amelia_Earhart#Planning) from Wikipedia shows the final two planned legs of her flight being:

> July 3, 1937 Howland Island   to  Honolulu, Hawaii     1900 NM  Planned
>   leg
>
> July 4, 1937  Honolulu, Hawaii to Oakland, California  2400 NM  Planned
>   leg

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen it as it isn't inline in the page, but (inexplicably) you have to *click to show* in order to expand it. Thanks.